# Variable `undefined` in Vimeo API method

Tags: javascript, angular, undefined, vimeo

So I have embedded a vimeo video in my Angular 8 app and am now trying to trigger some animation after the video starts playing and once its ended. Essentially if screen width is `<800`, the variable `isMobile` is `true`. Next I have the vimeo `play` method being called which checks if `isMobile` is `true`, and sets `load_completed` (which is the animation trigger) to `true`. The isssue is that my variable `isMobile` returns `undefined`, why is that?

```js
  isMobile = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    console.log(this.innerWidth);
    if (this.innerWidth < 800) {
      this.isMobile = true;
    }

    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

    player.on('play', function() {
      //isMobile returns undefined why?
      console.log(this.isMobile);
      if (this.isMobile) {
        this.load_completed = true;
      }
      console.log('Played the video');
    });

    player.on('ended', function(data) {
      console.log('Video ended');
    });
  }
```

Comment: i think when you are writing it in `function()` `this` is loosing its context so did you try writing an arrow function like `player.on('play',()=>{//your code})`

Comment: Okay this worked! But why? Isn't this `function()` and this `()=>` the same? just a different syntax?

Comment: No the reason is when you are using a function that points to a global scope leading to a change of context in this while using an arrow function the context of this is to immediate parent on which the arrow function is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as follows , here is the [`explanation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

```
player.on('play',()=>{
 console.log(this.isMobile);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here actually.

Arrow functions as mentioned [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59128020/3209523) by default uses `this` as the `this` of currently defined place.

Or you can bind the `this` in the definition of the function

```
player.on('play',function (){
 console.log(this.isMobile);
}.bind(this));
```